# How to configure hibernate dialect to support multiple array types?

Tags: hibernate

I have a native query that returns sql array:

```
select person.id as personid, array_agg(car.model) as personscarsmodels
from person join car on person.id = car.ownerpersonid
group by person.id
```

To add support for sql arrays in hibernate I added to pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hibernate will correctly return an array of strings, when I configure my custom dialect like this:

```
public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {

    public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "string-array"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void contributeTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);

        typeContributions.contributeType(StringArrayType.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

The question is how to add support for **both** string and int arrays so that I can add similar query but now with int array. If I configure dialect like this:

```
public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {

    public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "string-array");
        registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "int-array");
    }

    @Override
    public void contributeTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);

        typeContributions.contributeType(StringArrayType.INSTANCE);
        typeContributions.contributeType(IntArrayType.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

this exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do that:

```
registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "string-array");
registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "int-array");
```

The second call practically overrides the second one. That's why you get the error.

You can only register a JDBC `Type` to a single Hibernate `Type`. So, in your case, you could use a generic `Object[]` Type for that.

Comment: thanks, so I need to call registerHibernate with what params exactly? Is Object[] supported by hibernate-types-52.jar? would it be converted in the result of the query to a list of correct type (int or string)?

Comment: Yes, you need to call it once. I didn't test it with an `Object[]` type before, but you can give eit a try and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to define custom UserType for array instead of using `hibernate-types-52` jar:

```
public class ArrayUserType implements UserType {

    public static final String HIBERNATE_TYPE_NAME = "arrayusertype";
    public static final ArrayUserType INSTANCE = new ArrayUserType();

    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.ARRAY };
    }

    public Class<List> returnedClass() {
        return List.class;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x == null ? y == null : x.equals(y);
    }

    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x == null ? 0 : x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        if (names != null && names.length > 0 && rs != null && rs.getArray(names[0]) != null) {

            Object[] array = (Object[]) rs.getArray(names[0]).getArray();

            List list = new ArrayList();
            for (Object element : array) {
                list.add(element);
            }

            return list;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        // does not seem to be needed just for getting an array from db
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        // does not seem to be needed just for getting an array from db
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }
}
```

and register it in a new custom dialect:

```
    public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {

        public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
            super();
            registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, ArrayUserType.HIBERNATE_TYPE_NAME);
        }

        @Override
        public void contributeTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
            super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);

            typeContributions.contributeType(ArrayUserType.INSTANCE, ArrayUserType.HIBERNATE_TYPE_NAME);
        }
    }
```